# a small noiseless motor with accurate RPM control?

Tags: motors

What kind of motor is suitable for the below requirements?

1. 2700 rpm, needs to be accurate, not +- few rpms. I think the best approach is to use a hall effect sensor and adjust current/voltage on the fly? Or a better idea?
2. Be as noiseless as possible. The noise 12V square fan motors make is perfect.
3. Torque is not much of an issue as even though it is rotating a 100g load on top of it the load is supported by 4 bearings.

What motor am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brushless motor controlled by an electronic speed controller can produce an accurate and relatively powerful system.

Most BLDC motors used for hobby r/c equipment would be suitable and these are capable of supporting a significant axial and tangential load.

When operating at low RPMs (2700 RPM is slow) good quality motors are virtually silent.

The speed controller (ESC) can be controlled by pwm or a coded signal such as sBus which would also provide an interface for a feedback system via a microcontroller.

BLDC motors are specified by the can size and the revs per volt rating. For example a 2216-900kv motor would be approximately 22mm dia, with 16mm magnets, rotating at 900 rpm per volt unloaded.  Small motors operate on 2S-4S LiPo batteries or 7v to 14v.

Comment: BLDC + ESC it is then

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a synchronous motor in order to obtain desired the rpm, it runs at a constant speed irrespective of and load there are various methods to control speed. The sound produced is dependent on the design-friction and others things.

In synchronous motors the stater and rotor rotates at the same speed. However, you may need to use a feed back system, because even it works in magnetic locking it drops rpm when loading.

I am not sure about the power supply nature either AC or DC, this was not mentioned in the question?